# How to make this MySQL select list query faster ?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I have the following MySQL query which my web server executes using SQL Alchemy ORM

```
(db_session.query(self.orm_model.time,
                  self.orm_model.temperature,
                  self.orm_model.fan_speed)
           .filter(self.orm_model.cook_session_id == model.cook_session_id))
```

My temperature data table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `smoker_temp` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cook_session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `temperature` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'AA',
  `fan_speed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cook_session_id` (`cook_session_id`),
  KEY `time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4215274 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I run load test on my web server, this query seems to take the longest to run (i.e. it seems to be the bottleneck). The temperature data is coming in every second from many users, so the select query returns increasingly longer list. Furthermore, the write operations are performed on a different node. The above select query is executed less often than the insert. The requests build up, the CPU usage keeps increasing (both HTTP and database)and eventually some HTTP requests are dropped.

I have my database setup on AWS RDS and I execute select queries on a read only node which is separate from write node. In my understanding, AWS RDS will copy new data to read only node at regular intervals from where i execute these select queries.

Is there any way to reduce the execution time of this query, not just in terms of SQL but other solutions are also welcome like changing the db engine, using database other than mysql, adding/ altering indices, changing AWS infrastructure, using ORM other than SQLAlchemy, caching, stored procedures etc ?

The obvious solution would be to add more read-only nodes but that seems to only delay the eventual requests being dropped and does not resolve the bottleneck

Comment: One of the most important things you can do when using an ORM and something is slow is to find the SQL that it is generating.  ORMs are notorious for generating queries that are accurate but not optimal.  But wow, what's going on with cook_session_id being a `varchar(255)`?  If you really need a large value as a session token, you should have a table of those and an integer here... but first, find the generated query, and play with it manually, including examining the query plan, using `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

Comment: This is what the query looks like when I do print(query). `SELECT smoker_temp.time AS smoker_temp_time, 
smoker_temp.temperature AS smoker_temp_temperature, smoker_temp.fan_speed AS smoker_temp_fan_speed
FROM smoker_temp
WHERE smoker_temp.cook_session_id = %(cook_session_id_1)s`

Comment: I don't think the above query can be simplified any further. I will try creating a separate table to associate string 'cook_session_id' with a number. However, do you think it would be faster to search for numeric id in a different table and then search for temp data based on numeric id rather than just one query based on string id ?

Comment: Now that you have the query in hand, run it directly on the server with differing arguments.  How does it perform?  Yes, I would expect that the query with 2 tables would be faster than 1, but that is something you can easily test rather than making any code changes based in assumptions.

Comment: We changed cook_session_id and other 'id' fields in other tables from varchar(255) to char(36) as we are using UUID (which has constant length of 36) for those values and that seems to have improved performance.